# How do I return an elements class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to send the class of an element to a function. Basically, I need to tell showAjaxLoader() that it should show the loading icon for the element being clicked!

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var showAjaxLoader = function(selector) {
        $(selector).empty().html('<img src="loading.gif" />');
        };

    $(".add")
        .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
            var class = this.class;
            showAjaxLoader(class);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in Javascript, so you can't use it as a variable name. It's not available as a property of an element: you need to use the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) property instead.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var showAjaxLoader = function(message) {
            alert(message)
        };

    $(".add")
        .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
            var className = this.className;
            showAjaxLoader(className);
    });
});
```

Comment: awesome. It works. What if I wanted the class name of the parent? I tried var selector = this.parent.className; but that wont work :/

Comment: @Mohamad `this.parentNode.className`. Or, jQuery style, `$(this).parent().attr('class')`.